# What is different between cloud.[CustomDomain].com and pages.[CustomDomain].com for SSL Certificate?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, landing-page, ssl, cloudpagesurl

Could you please help me clarify what difference between **cloud** and **page** for the domain when setup SSL

here are detail I found:

- **Cloud Pages:**  Secure cloud.[CustomDomain].com URLs that are used for presenting content in landing pages
- **Legacy Landing Pages:**  Secure pages.[CustomDomain].com URLs that are used for presenting content on the landing page

So not sure what is Legacy landing page in SFMC CloudPage

reference - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000339842&type=1

Answer (score 0):

Legacy Landing Pages are, as the name indicates: Legacy. [Since August 2021 release](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000356364&type=1) it has not been possible to create new Landing Pages, and the feature will be removed from SFMC in June 2022, with all existing Legacy Landing Pages being unpublished and no longer available on the web.

If you want to ensure all your subdomains are secured, you should instead focus on the other ones listed in the article you are referencing:

- **Cloud Pages:**  Secure cloud.[CustomDomain].com URLs that are used for presenting content in landing pages
- **Email Tracking Links:**  Secure click.[CustomDomain].com URLs that are used in email content for tracking recipient click engagement.
- **Email View as a Web Page:**  Secure view.[CustomDomain].com URLs that are used in email content for recipients to view the content in a web browser.
- **Portfolio and Content Builder Content:**  Secure image.[CustomDomain].com URLs for content stored in Marketing Cloud content tools that are used in emails, cloud pages or landing pages.

However, if you request the SSL from Salesforce (which I would recommend) they will ensure the SSL will be provisioned and applied so it secures all the relevant domains and links. Managing the SSL certs yourself is not only complex, but also risky, as you need to renew them and provide them to Salesforce in time for them to be replaced before their expiration.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail and your clarification!

Comment: You are welcome @user110038 - please remember to mark the answer as accepted